# JSX/Photoshop - Good reference material with examples?

Tags: reference, photoshop, extendscript

I really appreciate community efforts for sharing knowledge via reference documentes but I'd like to know if there exist really good material for JSX scripting learning.

Adobe has very well organized reference docs but the examples are poor. XTools has good examples, but it´s desorganized and incomplete.

I wonder if there exist any reference book designed by good educators or, at list, people with a great common sense related to educational material design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel your pain. I was in a similar position when I first started out Photoshop scripting
I got my hands on a book called [Adobe Scripting](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Adobe-Scripting-Blueprint-Photoshop-Illustrator/dp/0764524550/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1413794327&sr=8-1&keywords=photoshop%20scripting) which has lots of examples, which I found useful. It's old, but still useful as most of it is still relevant. Various aspects of newer versions of Photoshop have made things easier. But avoid The Photoshop CS2 Speed Clinic as it wasn't so useful and only mentions actions.

For doing UI stuff then I strongly recommend [Script UI](http://www.kahrel.plus.com/indesign/scriptui.html) as without it doing any user interface code is major headache.

Stick with it. Ask questions here, or on the Adobe Photopshop Scripting Forums.

Illegitimi non carborundum

Comment: A kind and useful answer, indeed. Many thanks Ghoul Fool. I'll check them right now.

Comment: Adobe Scripting Used: £0.01 + £2.80 UK delivery. Give me a brake! lol

Comment: the xtools forum is also good for questions - i almost always got a very useful response from the guys over there regardless of whether or not my problem was to do with xtools.